# Having problems with scikit learn one hot encoding columns

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I am currently writing scikit learn one hot encoding scripts, but when I go to print the columns only one prints, when there are four. Down below are the code for the one hot encoding and the head of the dataframe. I am confused because when I change the X back to df in line 9 all the columns print, but at the end when I print the last line only the first column prints.

```
Code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

X = df = pd.read_csv('Filename.txt')
#print(X.head(4))

X = X.select_dtypes(include=[object])
#print(X.head(4))

print(X.shape)

from sklearn import preprocessing

print(df.columns)

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

X_2 = X.apply(le.fit_transform)
#print(X_2.head())

enc = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()

enc.fit(X_2)

onehotlabels = enc.transform(X_2).toarray()
onehotlabels.shape
#print(onehotlabels)

Dataframe head:
2019-05-02,6,9,5
2019-05-01,0,4,4
2019-04-30,5,4,4
2019-04-29,2,4,7
2019-04-28,7,5,2
```

Comment: pd.get_dummies check

Comment: I already used pd.dummies but, I would rather use scikitlearn's one hot since I am going to continue to use it when I start my SVM.